# Writing Django model to optimize complex filtering

Tags: python, django, models

I have this real-estate data for thousands of houses:

This is data for one house:

Year, Low_Price, High_Price

1999, $125,000, $146,000

2000, $122,000, $148,000

2001, $127,000, $149,000

2002, $129,000, $151,000

2003, $134,000, $153,000

2004, $138,000, $164,000

2005, $145,000, $158,000

I would like to filter by Year, Low_Price, and High_Price.
For example, search for housing prices between 2002 - 2004, between $128,000 - $152,0000.

If search parameters match that of the model, the house is shown.
This is a lot of data for one model to filter through and I'm not sure how to set up the model.

Writing out the model like so:

```
price_low_1999 = $125,000
price_high_1999 = $146,000
etc...
```

seems far from ideal for every single model.

How would I go about setting up the models so it would be easy to filter through this data given the above search parameters?

Comment: What's wrong with using `__range`?

Comment: Because the data is not written in the manner of 1999-2004, $125,000 - $158,000, but instead I need to specifically be able to match prices for one particular year and a range.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a problem if you setup the model like:

```
class House(models.Model):
   year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
   low_price = models.FloatField()
   high_price = models.FloatField()
   # other house attributes ...
```

and you filter e.g. for a housing price between 2002 - 2004 and $128,000 - $152,000

```
houses = House.objects.filter(
                                 year__range=(2002, 2004), 
                                 low_price__gte=128.000, 
                                 high_price__lte=152.000
                              )
```

is this something you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need two models, one for house, and one for yearly price (fields house(foreign key), year, price_low and price_high). Then you can query with `House.objects.filter(pk__in=Prices.objects.filter(year__gte=2012, year__lte=2014, price_low__gte=100000).values('house_id'))`